# How to check if chekcbox is checked

Tags: javascript

I have a table where each row has a checkbox inside.

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="handleClickOnReduce(this)" checked="">
```

The handler works like this:

```
function handleClickOnReduce (dom) {
  console.log(dom)
  if (dom.checked === 'true') {
    console.log('checked')
  }
  if (dom.toString().includes('checked')) {
    console.log('checked')
  }
  if (stompClient) {
    var chatMessage = {
      sender: 'userRequest',
      content: [dom.parentElement.id],
      type: 'REDUCE'
    }
    stompClient.send('/app/chat.sendMessage', {}, JSON.stringify(chatMessage))
  }
}
```

You can see already what my question is about. I try to figure out if the checkbox of the caller of the handleClockOnReduce function is checked or unchecked.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dom.checked` has the boolean value `true` which is different from the string `"true"`. Either compare to `true`:

```
  if(dom.checked === true)
```

Or just take the boolean itslef as condition:

```
  if(dom.checked)
```

The other condition you've shown

```
  if (dom.toString().includes('checked'))
```

is very error prone as `<option id="checked">` would also match.